# How to mock String.equals in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

For testing purpose i need to override 'equals' method:

```
def any = [equals: { true }] as String
any == 'should be true'
// false
```

More detailed about problem:

```
class EmployeeEndpointSpec extends RestSpecification {

    void "test employee" () {
        when:
            get "/v1/employee", parameters
        then:
            expectedStatus.equals(response.statusCode)
            expectedJson.equals(response.json)
        where:
            parameters  << [
                [:],
                [id: 824633720833, style: "small"]
            ]
            expectedStatus << [
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                HttpStatus.OK
            ]
            expectedJson << [
                [errorCode: "badRequest"],
                [
                    id: 824633720833,
                    name: "Jimmy",
                    email: "jimmy@fakemail.com",
                    dateCreated:"2015-01-01T01:01:00.000", // this value should be ignored
                    lastUpdated: "2015-01-01T01:01:00.000" // and this
                ]
            ]
    }
}
```

`lastUpdated` and `dateCreated` may change in time, and i need 
somehow ignore them.

Comment: Please explain *why* you need to mock such a low-level method. There may well be a much better approach, such as mocking whatever is obtaining the strings.

Comment: I need it for testing REST response (JSON converted to Map). My task is check what returned response is same as expected, except some values - they should be ignored.  Example of response: `[sucess: "true", date: "2015-01-01"]`, and i want something like this `[sucess: "true", date: new AnyValue].equals(response)`.

Comment: Write the code of your unit test, and explain WHAT you want to test and not HOW.

Comment: So don't check those values... use something like Hamcrest. I see no reason for mocking in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no need to compare mentioned fields - remove them:

```
class EmployeeEndpointSpec extends RestSpecification {

    void "test employee" () {
        when:
            get "/v1/employee", parameters
        then:
            expectedStatus.equals(response.statusCode)
            def json = response.json
            json.remove('dateCreated')
            json.remove('lastUpdated')
            expectedJson.equals(response.json)
        where:
            parameters  << [
                [:],
                [id: 824633720833, style: "small"]
            ]
            expectedStatus << [
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                HttpStatus.OK
            ]
            expectedJson << [
                [errorCode: "badRequest"],
                [
                    id: 824633720833,
                    name: "Jimmy",
                    email: "jimmy@fakemail.com",
                    dateCreated:"2015-01-01T01:01:00.000",
                    lastUpdated: "2015-01-01T01:01:00.000"
                ]
            ]
    }
}
```

I'd also separate testing negative and positive scenarios.

You can also test `keySet()` separately from testing keys values instead of comparing the whole map. This is the way I'd do that:

```
then:
def json = response.json
json.id == 824633720833
json.name == "Jimmy"
json.email == "jimmy@fakemail.com"
json.dateCreated.matches('<PATTERN>')
json.lastUpdated.matches('<PATTERN>')
```

In case You don't like the last two lines it can be replaced with:

```
json.keySet().contains('lastUpdated', 'dateCreated')
```

Comment: But what if JSON is nested ? The removal of these fields from a nested maps will be tedious

Comment: @AndreyT, in the example above JSON isn't nested. Please provide a real world example then, because it seems that I try to solve incorrect problem.

Comment: it's real example, but i try found answer for the future tests too. Thanks.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of whole evil. If this answer satisfies You, please accept or upvote it. In a moment I'll add a preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
String.metaClass.equals = { Object _ -> true }
```

Comment: The other answer and comments are useful, but thanks for answering what he actually asked.